# Output entry in table according to row column

Tags: excel

What is the best way to output a specific entry in a table using the row and column as input.

For example output(A,1)=X  output(A,2)=Z   output(B,1)=Y

```
  1  2  3  4
A X  Z  X  R
B Y  R  Y  R
C X  X  R  Z
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

vlookup should do it

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A1:D4,C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `C` is in A4, then:

```
=OFFSET(A1,G1,H1)
```

should return the required letters where H1 contains the value at the top of the relevant column and G1 the numeric equivalent of the letter (ie C > `3`) at the left of the row.

With little adjustment G1 could be entered as a letter or letters but that would get complicated for more than 26 rows of data.